# Chi-square distribution

Tags: probability

I have questions about Chi-square distribution

Find $a$ and $b$ that achieve:

$P[a\leq \chi^2 \leq b]=0.9$

such that

$P[\chi^2\geq b]=0.05$
( fredom degrees 10)
I think:
$P[\chi^2\geq b]=1-P[\chi^2\leq b]=1-0.05=0.95$

so

$P[a\leq \chi^2\leq b]=P[\chi^2\leq b]-P[X^2\leq a]=0.9$

$P[a\leq\chi^2\leq b]=0.95-P[\chi^2\leq a]=0.9$

$P[\chi^2\leq a]=0.05$

so 
$a=18.307$

true? and what about b?

**another question, if i want to find $X^2_{(20,0.95)}$ how?**

[image]

Comment: What's the number of degrees of freedom of the $\chi^2$ distribution you have?

Comment: Sorry, i forget it, it is equal to 10.

Answer (score 1):

From $\Bbb P\{\chi_{\nu}^2\ge b\}=0.05$ we have
$$
\Bbb P\{\chi_{\nu}^2\ge b\}=1-\Bbb P\{\chi_{\nu}^2\le b\}\quad \Longrightarrow \quad \Bbb P\{\chi_{\nu}^2\le b\}=0.95
$$
and from $\Bbb P\{a\le\chi_{\nu}^2\le b\}=0.9$ we have
$$
\Bbb P\{a\le\chi_{\nu}^2\le b\}=\Bbb P\{\chi_{\nu}^2\le b\}-P\{\chi_{\nu}^2\le a\}=0.95-P\{\chi_{\nu}^2\le a\}=0.9
$$
and then $$ \Bbb P\{\chi_{\nu}^2\le a\} =0.95-0.9=0.05$$ and $$ \Bbb P\{\chi_{\nu}^2\ge a\} =1-0.05=0.95$$.

So you can find the values from the table for $\nu=10$. So we have $b=18.307$ directly and evaluate  $a=3.94 $ as linear interpolation.

An $\alpha$ quantile $q_{\alpha}$ is the value such that
$$
\Bbb P\{\chi_{\nu}^2\le q_{\alpha}\}=\alpha
$$
or equivalently
$$
\Bbb P\{\chi_{\nu}^2\ge q_{\alpha}\}=1-\alpha
$$
The table gives the quantile $q_{\alpha}=\chi_{\nu,\,\alpha}^2$ values as 
$$\Bbb P\{\chi_{\nu}^2\ge \chi_{\nu,\alpha}^2\}=1-\alpha.$$

So we have for the quantile $q_{0.95}=\chi_{\nu,\,0.95}^2$
$$\Bbb P\{\chi_{20}^2\ge \chi_{20,\,0.95}^2\}=1-0.95=0.05$$
that is
$$
\chi_{20,\,0.95}^2=31.410
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X \sim \chi^2 (\nu = 10)$.  You have two conditions:  $$\Pr[a \le X \le b] = 0.90, \quad \Pr[X \ge b] = 0.05.$$  From the second condition, we can read it directly from the table:  for $DF = \nu = 10$, we look at the tenth row of the table, and we look at the column "$0.05$", which gives $b \approx 18.307$.  (A more precise value from a computer is $b \approx 18.30703805$.)

Note that the table gives you the **upper** tailed quantiles of the distribution, not the lower.  So if you are looking in the "$0.05$" column, you are finding $$\Pr[X > \text{cell value}] = 0.05,$$ where by "cell value" I mean the value displayed in one of the rows in that column corresponding to the degrees of freedom of the distribution.

Then, to get the value of $a$, we note that $$\Pr[X \ge a] = \Pr[a \le X \le b] + \Pr[X \ge b] = 0.90 + 0.05 = 0.95,$$ so we look in the same row but in the column "$0.95$"--oh wait, **no such column exists in your table!**  What do you do?

Option 1:  [Get a better table.](http://passel.unl.edu/Image/Namuth-CovertDeana956176274/chi-sqaure%20distribution%20table.PNG)  This would show you that $a \approx 3.940$.

Option 2:  [Consult Wolfram Alpha.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Quantile[ChiSquareDistribution[10],0.05])  Again, you get the same result.

Option 3:  Interpolate.  This is very crude.  We interpolate between the two adjacent columns that are to either side of $0.95$, namely "$0.975$" and "$0.20$".  This is hardly ideal, but with this method you would calculate $$a \approx \frac{0.95-0.20}{0.975-0.20} \cdot 3.247 + \frac{0.975-0.95}{0.975 - 0.20} \cdot 13.442 \approx 3.57587.$$  This is very poor because the inverse CDF of the chi-square distribution is hardly linear on this interval.

Option 4:  Newton's method.  This is computationally intensive but technically possible on a hand calculator.  Recall that the chi-square PDF with $\nu$ degrees of freedom is $$f_X(x) = \frac{2^{-\nu/2} x^{\nu/2-1} e^{-x/2}}{\Gamma(\nu/2)}, \quad x > 0,$$ hence for $\nu = 10$ we have $$\Pr[X \le a] = \int_{x=0}^a \frac{x^4 e^{-x/2}}{768} \, dx.$$  Tabular integration by parts gives $$\Pr[X \le a] = 1 - e^{-a/2}\left(1 + \frac{a}{2} + \frac{a^2}{8} + \frac{a^3}{48} + \frac{a^4}{384}\right) = p(a)$$  We seek the solution to $p(a) = 0.05$, or equivalently, the positive real root to $g(a) = p(a) - \frac{1}{20} = 0.$  Because $g'(a) = f_X(a)$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus, the Newton's method recursion gives us $$a_{n+1} = a_n - \frac{g(a_n)}{g'(a_n)} = -\frac{3648 e^{a_n/2}}{5
   a_n^4}+\frac{768}{a_n^4}+\frac{384}{a_n^3}+\frac{96}{a_n^2}+a_n+\frac{16}{a_n}+2.$$  Then with the initial guess $a_0 = 4$ (based on the value of the upper $0.975$ quantile), we obtain the sequence $$\{4., 3.94119, 3.9403, 3.9403, \ldots \}$$ which gives us rapid convergence within a few iterations to the result.  I didn't say it was *pretty*, but it works.